# Not receiving appropriate JSON response from Server

Tags: android, python, json, flask, android-volley

I'm trying to communicate between Android and a Flask server I've set up on AWS. I have some data I've put inside a `JSONObject`, and I'm sending that over a POST request to the server.

The Flask server receives this JSON, parses it, and even does the appropriate manipulations. However, when I send a `Response` back to Android, it doesn't seem to identify it at all.

I believe I'm going wrong in the `Flask` return part, but I don't know where exactly.

Here's the `Flask` return code:

```
parsed_results = parse_text(results)

#json_x = json.dumps({'id':str(status.inserted_id), 'Result':'OK', 'data': parsed_results})
return Response(json.dumps({'id': str(status.inserted_id), 'Result': 'OK', 'data': parsed_results, 'raw_data': results}), mimetype='application/json'), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Here's the Android `Listener` code:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            URL,
            data,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("JSON_TAG", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    )

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return super.getParams();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            //return super.getHeaders();
            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            return headers;
        }
};
```

The Android application just stays idle. Where am I going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue, guys. The problem was very apparent - a mismatched return statement from the server. By using `jsonify`, I was able to return the data to the server.

```
from flask import jsonify

results = parse_results(data)

return jsonify(results)
```

Worked like a charm!